# How to dynamically change column name in resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi have a this request :

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TEST
```

And I have another table with these data:

```
-----------------
| COL   | VALUE |
-----------------
| COL1  | TOTO  |
-----------------
| COL2  | TATA  |   
-----------------
| COL3  | TITI  |  
-----------------
```

I want to have a resultset of the request looks like that :

```
---------------------
| TOTO| TATA | TITI |
---------------------
```

Instead of

```
---------------------
| COL1| COL2 | COL3 |
---------------------
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't really get it. Do you want to pivot?

Comment: No my data are displayed correctly. The aim is only to change the column name (COL1, COL2, COL3) by it's corresponding value located in another table)

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic SQL to generate a statement with the correct alias for each column. A decent implementation will require error checking to verify that the columns to be aliased all exist in the source table. Rather than do this in T-SQL, the aliasing might be better done in a consuming application.

Answer (score 1):

To make it dynamic you can use a dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cols = N'';
SELECT @cols += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(value) FROM (SELECT value FROM dbo.test) x
SELECT @cols

SET @sql = N'
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT [col],[value] FROM [dbo].[test]) P
PIVOT (MIN(value) FOR COL IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@cols, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's posible, but if it is, you will need to do a subquery.

Something like that:

```
SELECT 
COL1 as (SELECT value FROM anothertablewiththesedata WHERE condition),
COL2 as (SELECT value FROM anothertablewiththesedata WHERE condition),
COL3 AS (SELECT value FROM anothertablewiththesedata WHERE condition)
FROM TEST
```

Maybe it's tricky or imposible.

Can someone confirm or correct me? :)

Comment: unfortunately you can't do that, gives you `Incorrect syntax near '('.
`

Comment: Check @RoundFour answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using dynamic SQL.

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql='SELECT 
COL1 as ' + (SELECT value FROM anothertablewiththesedata WHERE col = 'col1') + ' ,
COL2 as ' + (SELECT value FROM anothertablewiththesedata WHERE col = 'col2') + ' ,
COL3 as ' + (SELECT value FROM anothertablewiththesedata WHERE col = 'col3') + ' ,
FROM TEST'

exec @sql
```